# TermGroup, TermSet, name and label max length

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I was wondering what the max. length restrictions are for SharePoint Online Managed Metadata Service:
 - TermGroup name
 - TermSet name
 - Term/Label name/value

I could not find anything on MSDN. A link to a source or reference would be fantastic, too.

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick test and it seems
TermGroup, TermSet and the Term have 255 character limit:

[image]

**I don't think it is documented**

Answer (score 0):

A note in the dot net doc's for the Label (value) matches the findings from @SharePointer

> The Label can not have more than 255 characters, and cannot contain
>   any invalid characters including: semicolon, double quote, left angle
>   bracket, right angle bracket, ampersand, pipe, and tab.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.label.value?view=sharepoint-server#exceptions

Similar results are available for the other wonderings:

https://www.google.com/search?q=SharePoint.Taxonomy+255+site%3Adocs.microsoft.com