# Max length of a single metadata value

Tags: metadata, file-metadata

I was looking at the [Software boundaries and limits docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) but I can't find the specific value  of the maximum allowed length of a single metadata value.

Comment: Do you mean managed metadata created through term store?

Comment: you have similar question with answer here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214136/termgroup-termset-name-and-label-max-length